# Store list values in a string in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, c#-4.0

I have a list which stores some string values.

**Code:**

```
List<VBCode> vbCodes = new List<VBCode>();

public class VBCode
{
    public string Formula { get; set; }
}
```

In a method I am trying to append the list values.

```
public void ListValue()
  {
    if (vbCodes.Count > 0)
      {
         StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
         foreach (var item in vbCodes)
           {
             strBuilder.Append(item).Append(" || ");
           }
         string strFuntionResult = strBuilder.ToString();
      }
   }
```

The list will have values like shown below

[image]

How can I get the formula values and append in the foreach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are appending the `item object` you need to `append` the `object property Formula`

```
public void ListValue()
  {
    if (vbCodes.Count > 0)
      {
         StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
         foreach (var item in vbCodes)
           {
             strBuilder.Append(item.Formula).Append(" || ");
           }
         string strFuntionResult = strBuilder.ToString();
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this simply without `foreach` by using `String.Join()`, it will be like this :

```
 string strFuntionResult = String.Join(" || ", vbCodes.Select(x=>x.Formula).ToList());
```

If you really want to iterate using foreach means you have to get `Formula` from the iterator variable also take care to remove the final `||` after completing the iteration, if so the code would be like the following:

```
StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
foreach (var item in vbCodes)
{
    strBuilder.Append(item.Formula).Append(" || ");
}
string strFuntionResult = strBuilder.ToString(); // extra || will be at the end
// To remove that you have to Trim those characters 
// or take substring till that
strFuntionResult = strFuntionResult.Substring(0, strFuntionResult.LastIndexOf('|'));
```